# Groovy SQL Execute Parameters not getting replaced

Tags: sql, variables, jdbc, groovy, parameters

This problem is frustrating me so much, that I've finally created a Stackoverflow Account - this is my first question here, go easy on me.

I've got an SQL Script like this:

```
select * from d_table 
where id = :line;
```

I'd like to execute that query from a groovy script. So far I've written this:

```
static void main(String[] args) {
    String dbURL = 'some.db:Port:serviceName'
    String dbUser = 'dbUser'
    String dbPw = 'aReallyStrongPassword'
    
    // connect to SQL Instance and DB
    def sql = Sql.newInstance(dbURL, dbUser, dbPw, 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver')

    // read Inputfile from local dir
     new File("inputfile.csv").eachLine { inputLine ->
        // loop over Inputfile
        try {
            // read SQL Script from local dir
            String sqlString = new File("script.sql").getText("UTF-8")
            // execute SQL Script, replace :line with input-ID
            resp = sql.execute sqlString, line: inputLine

        } catch(Exception e) {
            println(e)
        }
    }

    // close SQL Session
    sql.close()
}
```

But I'll always get an error like this:

```
WARNING: Failed to execute: select * from d_table 
where id = :line; because: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

I've got the feeling the query is not built properly, but I don't know whats the problem?
Using groovy 3.0.4.

Comment: remove `;` from the end of select query

Comment: damn that was so easy, that I feel stupid now. thank you!